# How to get multi-line tooltips to work with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple task: Get a multiline tooltip to work on a `span` in AngularJS.  Following various instructions I've read online, I've tried:

1. Using ng-attr-title and then  as a carriage return.
2. Using data-html and data-original-title and then 
    as a carriage return.
3. Using data-html and data-title and then 
    as a carriage return.

None of these appear to work.  What else can I try to get multi-line tooltips with AngularJS?

Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use $sce.trustAsHtml to bind html to the ng-attr-title with multi lines. See below,

```
var app = angular.module('tooltipApp',[]);

var ctrl = app.controller('tooltipAppCtrl',['$scope','$sce',function($scope, $sce){
   $scope.text = $sce.trustAsHtml('Line1 \n Line2');
}])

<body ng-app='tooltipApp'>
  <div ng-controller='tooltipAppCtrl'>
    <span ng-attr-title={{text}}>See tool tip</span>
  </div>
</body>
```